# Passing an array to d3.scale.ordinal().domain()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Why can't I introduce an array to .domain?

```
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['Oct-2011','Nov-2011','Dec-2011']))
```

but this doesn't

```
var foo= ['Oct-2011','Nov-2011','Dec-2011'];
...
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain([foo]))
```

I don't want to introduce the months manually because I don't want to update this code.

Comment: Look at `.domain([foo])`, `foo` is already an array, you don't need to wrap it in another array.  Just do `.domain(foo)`...

Comment: ah silly me, thank you!